# How to find the character of $\mathfrak{U}\left(\mathfrak{n}_{-}\right)$?

Tags: lie-algebras, characters

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a Kac-Moody algebra.

Then
$$
\mathfrak{n}_{-}=\oplus_{\alpha\in\varPhi_{+}}\mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha}
$$

and for $\mathfrak{U}\left(\mathfrak{n}_{-}\right)$ the Poincaré–Birkhoff–Witt basis is the family of monomials
$$
\prod_{\alpha\in\Phi_{+}}\prod_{k=1}^{m_{\alpha}}\epsilon\left(e_{-\alpha,k}\right)$$
where $m_\alpha$ is the multiplicity of root $\alpha$ and $\epsilon:\mathfrak g \rightarrow \mathfrak{Ug}$ is the universal algebra of $\mathfrak g$ [Serre, pp.11-14; Kac, p. 152].

We now wish to show that
$$
\mathrm{ch}\left(\mathfrak{U}\left(\mathfrak{n}_{-}\right)\right)=\prod_{\alpha\in\Phi_{+}}\left(1+\exp\left(-\alpha\right)+\exp^{2}\left(-\alpha\right)+\ldots\right)^{m_{\alpha}}
$$

**Questions:**

- How can it be done?
- In particular, what would be the definition of the character of $\mathfrak{U}\left(\mathfrak{n}_{-}\right)$?

**References:**
[Kac] V. Kac. Infinite-dimensional Lie algebras. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1990
[Serre] J-P. Serre. Lie algebras and Lie groups. 1964 lectures given at Harvard University, Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 1500, (2006)

Comment: Why the universal-algebra tag? (the epsilon is not a universal algebra in the sense of the tag, I'm pretty sure) Gerhard "Not Seeing The Generality Here" Paseman, 2015.02.13

Comment: @GerhardPaseman The question involves universal algebra of a Lie subalgebra, but I have removed the universal-algebra tag in case it is unnecessary.

Comment: That's the "universal enveloping algebra."  "Universal algebra" is something totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of the PBW theorem; since taking associated graded does not change characters, the character is $U(\mathfrak{n}_-)$ is the same as $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathfrak{n}_-)$, which is exactly the product you wrote down.